# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors in sympy returns empty brackets

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I am trying to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 4x4 matrix R. For this I use the commands R.eigenvals() and R.eigenvects() from sympy, however, python returns empty brackets. I know the eigenvalues are 1 and e^(+-2ix). Am I doing something wrong?

```
import pprint    
from sympy import *    

R=Matrix([[(cos(x))**2, -cos(x)*sin(x), -cos(x)*sin(x), (sin(x))**2],[cos(x)*sin(x), (cos(x))**2, -(sin(x))**2, -cos(x)*sin(x)],      [cos(x)*sin(x), -(sin(x))**2, (cos(x))**2, -cos(x)*sin(x)],           [(sin(x))**2, sin(x)*cos(x), sin(x)*cos(x), (cos(x))**2]])    

pprint (R)    
pprint (R.eigenvals())    
pprint (R.eigenvects())
```

Comment: code works perfectly fine with `x = 0.5` and Python 3.4-64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. As a workaround, one could try to find the eigenvalues "manually" by explicitly computing and solving the characteristic polynomial.

```
lam = sp.symbols('lambda')
cp = sp.det(R - lam * sp.eye(4))
eigs = sp.solveset(cp, lam)
eigs
```

> ```
> {1, 
> -sqrt(2)*sqrt(cos(4*x) - 1)/2 + cos(2*x),
> sqrt(2)*sqrt(cos(4*x) - 1)/2 + cos(2*x)}
> ```

Note that the eigenvalues are provided in terms of real-valued trigonometric factors, since the latter are the factors of the characteristic polynomial. However, since `cos(4*x)-1` cannnot be positive, the last two eigenvalues are in fact complex.

Motivated by this observation, one can attempt for a cleaner eigenvalue expression by re-writing the trigonometric factors of the characteristic polynomial as complex exponentials. Indeed,

```
eigs_v2 = sp.solveset(cp.rewrite(sp.exp).simplify(), lam)
eigs_v2
```

> `{1, exp(-2*I*x), exp(2*I*x)}`